# DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT ignored when running from the command line

Tags: .net-core, environment-variables

I have a .Net Core 3.1 app that runs fine from Visual Studio but I can't run it from the command line.  From the exception that gets thrown I can tell that it's not reading my `appsettings.Development.json file`.  (I have both ASPNET_ENVIRONMENT AND DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT both set to Development and started a new command window.)

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Comment: @Mikkel, I think what happens is that it always uses values from `launchSettings.json`.  It ignores the environment variables.  But maybe if those values are left out of the `json` file it would use the environment?

Answer (score 1):

You can run your dll file like below

```
dotnet My.Favorite.Project.dll --environment Development
```